# initialize map in class not in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to add a marker to the map using the form. Can anyone help me? Installing the map works. I want to display markers after entering x and y, and read this data from the table. I have 2 inputs, one for X and the other for Y after clicking "add" I add this data to the table and I have 2 objects, etc ... but only one marker from state.items is displayed on the map, although I have more coordinates in the table.I know that the componentDidMount () method is only run once and here is the problem. i trying initialize map in class, not in componentDidMount.
anyone would help me write this in code?

```
state={
items:[{
      "X": 13.6155611,
      "Y": 51.0331258
    },
    ],
}

 addItem = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newItem = {
      "Y": parseFloat(this.state.X),
      "X": parseFloat(this.state.Y),
    };
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      items: [...prevState.items, newItem]
    }));

  }
componentDidMount() {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer,
      center: [this.state.lng, this.state.lat],
      zoom: this.state.zoom,
    });
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.items.length; i++) {
      var obj = this.state.items[i];
      let myLatlng = new mapboxgl.LngLat(obj.X, obj.Y);
      new mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat(myLatlng)
        .addTo(map);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to execute the code in `componentDidMount`, every time your state changes, consider using `componentDidUpdate(prevState, prevProps, snapshot)`

You have to be careful, using it, because you may end up creating an infinite loop. Try the following:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
  if (this.state.items.length !== prevState.items.length) {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer,
      center: [this.state.lng, this.state.lat],
      zoom: this.state.zoom,
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.items.length; i++) {
      var obj = this.state.items[i];
      let myLatlng = new mapboxgl.LngLat(obj.X, obj.Y);
      new mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat(myLatlng)
        .addTo(map);
    }
  }
}
```